# Drupal 7 views Contextual filters with Page & Blocks

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have an issue and i'm hoping to get some advise.

I have a view created that show content based on the url:

eg:

`domain.com/item/one`

Shows fields for my node with the title `one`

`domain.com/item/two`

Shows fields for my node with the title `two`

etc etc.

The path for the PAGE in views is set to `/item`

What I'm having trouble with is I need to have a BLOCK (becuase I'm making it collapsable) show under that page with the specific URL show the body field for that node.

eg:

`domain.com/item/three`

Shows fields for my node with the title `three` as well as a block that show the body field for node `three`

I have set the Contextual filter for the PAGE to:

```
Content: Title

When the filter value is NOT in the URL
Show "Page not found" 

Exception value : Empty (All removed)

Under More:
Case : Lowercase
Case in path : Lowercase

Transform spaces to dashes in URL : Checked
```

This works for the page but please let me know if I have set this up incorrectly.

I have set the same Contextual filter for BLOCK and it works in views preview but not on the page with the URL:

`domain.com/item/three`

Any advise on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I also tried adding `Global: Null` Contextual filter before the `Content: Title` filter which allowed me to put `item/three` in the preview and it works (before worked with just `three`). This also didn't work on the actual page.

Comment: Answered here: [http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13868/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-with-page-blocks][1]


  [1]: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13868/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-with-page-blocks